# How to set multiple ranges that when changed run multiple different macros?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

My question is pretty simple but for some reason I can't figure out how to do it. The thing is that I have 16 different ranges and 16 different macros.

The named ranges are:

- **GManA**
- **GVisA**
- **GManB**
- **GVisB**

It goes on until **GManH** and **GVisH**.

The macros I want to run are pretty similar. The problem is: whenever I make any changes to **GManA** OR **GVisA**, I run the macros **AttResA** and **CpGrlA**. Until this point, everything is right in the code, but I think everyone sees where I'm going with this. I want to extend this: whenever I make changes to **GManB** OR **GVisB**, it should run the macros **AttResB** and **CpGrlB**.

My code at the moment is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("GManA,GVisA")
If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then
    AttResA
    CpGrlA
End If
End Sub
```

How can I extend this?

Comment: You could use `Application.Run` and a loop through your specific ranges, but I'd have to question why you need 16 different subroutines. I'm guessing (could be wrong) that there's improvements to be made on that front first.

Answer (score 0):

I think it really depends what your other subs do. I would recommand changing the Sub to take in the changed cells.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Debug.Print "Target: " & Target.Address
    Set KeyCells = Intersect(Target, Range("GManA,GVisA"))
    If Not KeyCells Is Nothing Then
        AttResA KeyCells
        CpGrlA KeyCells
    Else
        Set KeyCells = Intersect(Target, Range("GManB,GVisB"))
        If Not KeyCells Is Nothing Then
            AttResB KeyCells
            CpGrlB KeyCells
        End If
    End If
    Set KeyCells = Nothing
End Sub

' Normal Module
Sub AttResA(ByRef Target As Range)
    Debug.Print "AttResA()", Target.Address
End Sub

Sub CpGrlA(ByRef Target As Range)
    Debug.Print "CpGrlA()", Target.Address
End Sub

Sub AttResB(ByRef Target As Range)
    Debug.Print "AttResB()", Target.Address
End Sub

Sub CpGrlA(ByRef Target As Range)
    Debug.Print "CpGrlB()", Target.Address
End Sub
```